# Corebluetooth terminate large data transfer without terminate bluetooth connection

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I am developing an app that needs to send large amounts of data between an iPhone and a device (it takes approximately 10 seconds to send the data). But I want to be able to cancel the data communication anytime. I am aware I can simply drop the connection to the device at anytime with

```
centralManager.cancelPeripheral(peripheral)
```

but that is not what I am actually looking for, as I want to stop sending data but without terminating the bluetooth connection.

Is there a way to terminate the data transmission without dropping the connection to the device?

the codes of sending data is as follow:

```
for (var Hex: UInt8 = 0x01; Hex <= 0x14; Hex+=1){
            var outbuffer = [UInt8](count: 16, repeatedValue: 0x00)
            outbuffer[0] = (0x68)
            outbuffer[1] = (Hex)
            let data = NSData(bytes: outbuffer, length: 7)
            print("data\(data)")
            connectingPeripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: connectingCharacteristicPassword , type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
```

}

Comment: Do you cut yourself small pieces of the large data or do you let the writing method do it for you?

Comment: i did not cut the data into small pieces. i just send all the data at one time and my time interval is running at 20ms.

Comment: I don't think you can stop the sending then.

Comment: You can't simply send a large block with CoreBluetooth, you can only send 20 bytes at a time this means that somewhere you are splitting your data up into 20 byte chunks. You simply need to stop this loop. Can you show any code?

Comment: yah, i'm actually sending 16 bytes at a time in a loop.

Comment: So you need to set a flag and check that in your loop.  If the flag is set, break out of the loop

Answer (score 1):

I figured that I would go ahead and give my input on this. There is no way in CoreBluetooth to stop the transmission of a data packet that has already been written to the output buffer. The reason for why this is the case is simply because it is not needed and it would be a useless functionality. The only reason for why you are having this issue is because your methodology is wrong in my opinion. Do not put everything in a for-loop and push the data all at once. Instead you should implement some sort of flow control mechanism.

In Bluetooth LE there are two main ways of writing data to a peripheral: “Write Commands” and “Write Requests”. You can look at it a bit like the TCP vs UDP protocols. With write commands you are just sending data without knowing whether or not the data was received by the application on the other side of the bluetooth link. With write requests you are sending data and letting the peripheral know that you want to be notified (ack’ed) that the data was in fact received. These two types are in CoreBluetooth called *CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse* and *CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse*. When writing data using the *CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse* (like you are doing in your code) you will get a *peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:* callback which verifies that the data has arrived at the other side. At this point you now have the option to go ahead and send the next packet if you want to, but if you for some reason want to stop sending data, then you can do that as well. Doing it this way you are in control of the whole flow and not just simply pushing everything though a for-loop.

**But wait, why would you ever want to use write commands then?** Well, since write requests requires the receiver to respond back to the sender it means that data must be sent in both directions. In this case, since the ack is sent by the application layer, you have to wait for the next connection interval before the ack can be sent. This means that when sending large amounts of data you can only send one packet per every two connection intervals which will give you a very poor overall bit rate.

With write commands, since they are not ack’ed, you can send as manny packets as possible within one connection event window. In most cases you should be able to send about 10-20 packets per connection window. But be aware that if you send too many packets then you will fill the outgoing buffer and packets will be lost. So, something that you can try is to directly send 9 packets with the *WriteWithoutResponse* type, followed by 1 packet of the *WriteWithResponse* type. After doing this you can wait for the *peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:* callback in which you can then send 10 more packets the same way. This way you will manage to send 10 packets per every 2 connection intervals while still being able to control the flow better.

You can of course experiment with the ratio a bit, but remember that the buffer is shared between multiple applications on the iOS device so you don’t want to be too close to the limit.